# Android Studio and Bitbucket plugin

Tags: android, plugins, android-studio, bitbucket

Suddenly when I try to checkout a project from BitBucket i get an error msg saying:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/ide/ui/ListCellRendererWrapper: com/intellij/ide/ui/ListCellRendererWrapper

NoClassDefFoundError: org/bitbucket/connectors/jetbrains/ui/BitbucketCloneProjectPanel$1: org/bitbucket/connectors/jetbrains/ui/BitbucketCloneProjectPanel$1
```

I tried to reinstall the plugin but no luck. Anyone please?

Comment: Download the latest one from here it works with all the versions of Android Studio https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads

Comment: Great, should I update my own answer with that link? I'm not currently on Android Studio anymore.

Comment: It would be great if you do that!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/issue/56/solved-plugin-does-not-work-well-with-idea

I just downloaded the version in this thread answer and updated it in Studio.

Edit:

Download the latest one from here it works with all the versions of Android Studio, https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads/

//Akbar Sha Ebrahim

Edit 2:

Unzip the file and then go to preferences (Settings on Windows), select Plugins header on the left, and choose "Install plugin from disk..." button on the right. Browse and select the bitbucket.jar file

//Tommie C.

Comment: Thank you so much there is the solution about the problem with bitbucket plugin on android studio.

Comment: Suggest you add that users should unzip the file and then go to preferences (Settings on Windows), select Plugins header on the left, and choose "Install plugin from disk..." button on the right. Browse and select the bitbucket.jar file.

Comment: Is this stil a help for ppl? Haven't done anything for Android in a long time.

Comment: The link for the zip is dead.

Comment: Not working on Android Studio v3.1.2 on 2018. (Can't share project to BitBucket)

Comment: Can we confirm this? I'm not working with Android studio anymore.

Answer (score 5):

For Android studio 13 it's failing with bitbucket plugin, try to install plugin https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector_IC-133.193.zip and reinstall the bitbucket plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As a prerequisite, create an account and a project in bitbucket
Then:

(1) Download latest plugin from: https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads/ and unzip it

(2) Open Android Studio --> New --> Plugin .--> Install Plugin from disk --> Navigate to bitbucket.jar inside your unzipped directory from (1)

[image: install plugin from disk]

(3) Restart android studio

(4) Go to tab New --> Project from Version Control --> Bitbucket
It will prompt for the bitbucket login

(5) Select your bitbucket repository where you want your project to be version controlled.