# How do we connect Android Studio with Github?

Tags: android-studio, github

we have a question.

First of all, we want to code an APP for Android using Android Studio and using Github for sharing it to each other.

We just started and both have no clue on how to achieve our goal. We also purchased a Team on github if that helps?

Greetings
Sean & Lukas

Comment: You mean use the Github repo to storage your project

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)

Comment: From the menu choose VCS -> Import into version control -> Share project on Github. The new popup will appear then you can enter your account credential to share.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
We tried that but..
We created a Team on github and we both joined this team with our own accounts. We both have admin rights ofc.

The thing now is that when we do that, we upload it on our accounts(!), not on the team.

Answer (score 0):

The link below has step by step instructions on linking android studio with github. The main thing is to make sure you have installed git on your computer.

[How to Link android studio with github](https://medium.com/code-yoga/how-to-link-android-studio-with-github-312037a13b99)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
We tried that but.. We created a Team on github and we both joined this team with our own accounts. We both have admin rights ofc. The thing now is that when we do that, we upload it on our accounts(!), not on the team.

Comment: I believe you will have to change the origin of the git repo to your teams link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990754/configure-android-studio-with-bitbucket-team-repo/45044355